# MySQL UPDATE on multiple JOINed tables

Tags: mysql

I trying to update Prestashop 1.6 data base: update one column on two tables depending on `WHERE name LIKE "%acana%"` from `ps_product_lang table` Unless there is no `UPDATE` query, everything goes fine. I tried various of solutions including from stackoverflow.com but none of them help me. I'm quite begginer at MySQL, but please understand.

```
select distinct ps_product_shop.id_product, name, ps_product.id_category_default from ps_product_shop
INNER JOIN ps_product ON ps_product_shop.id_product = ps_product.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product_shop.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product


UPDATE ps_product, ps_product_shop
SET id_category_default = '114'
WHERE name LIKE "%acana%" AND
ps_product.id_category_default LIKE "%111%";
```

l

Comment: Help me understand your need. You need update the column `id_category_default ` of which table? `ps_product` or `ps_product_shop`?

Comment: I need to set column id_category_default to "114" in ps_product_shop and ps_product_shop 
But the key is name of product given in table ps_product_lang

Comment: INNER JOIN of 'ps_product' and 'ps_product_lang' let me to get ID result based on product name.

Then I do next INNER JOIN to combine 'id_category_default' from 'ps_product' and 'ps_product_shop' to filter existing 'id_category_default' values (prestashop database make no sense to me)
And UPDATE to set unfiltered 'id_category_default' in following tables to '114'